# Split string, preserve quoted substring

Tags: python

I have a string that I'm trying to split such that the quoted substring stays preserved. Based on another thread here, I tried using `shlex`:

```
import shlex
shlex.split('“COBRA COMMANDER” Section 4Q/C')
```

However, the result isn't what I expected:

```
['“COBRA', 'COMMANDER”', 'Section', '4Q/C']
```

I need the quoted text in one batch, something like:

```
['“COBRA COMMANDER”', 'Section', '4Q/C']
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're encountering a classic prank by your operating system, editor, or the original source of the data, **"smart quotes"**, which are not `"`, but something else

```py
>>> ord('"')
34
>>> ord('“')
8220
```

Comment: That was it. The quotes come from a PDF that's being parsed, so I'll need to do a replace and then a `shlex.split(...)`, thank you. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm able.

Comment: alas / you may find you need to normalize characters like these (which are _of course_ not necessarily guaranteed to be a specific smart quote - they are too smart for that!), but you can directly detect and replace them in this instance

Comment: @easythrees are you trying to parse something that went through some OCR as a bash command? That is due to fail at some point. If it's not what you were trying to achieve (ie. you just wanted to preserve what's between quotes), I suggest using something else than `shlex`, as this library is specifically aimed at lexing a string as a shell would (hence the name), and shell tokenization has other rules than juste avoid splitting quotes; you'd probably be better off with regular expressions.

Comment: Hi @jthulhu, it's a PDF that was printed from a Word doc.